# style.setProperty changes css variables in html element but style of elements using those variables doesn't change

Tags: css, reactjs, css-variables

I'm using document.documentElement.style.setProperty("x", "y") to change values of css variables and for some reason this doesn't actually change them. When I inspect app with dev tools variables change in  at the top but not on the bottom and I'm not sure why.

[image]

Here's file with css variables on public repo: 
https://github.com/Neidz/fm_social-media-dashboard/blob/master/src/components/styles/variables.scss 
And here's react file that changes css variables: 
https://github.com/Neidz/fm_social-media-dashboard/blob/master/src/components/topPart.tsx

I'm trying to change all of values of variables starting with ct to the variables with the same name but starting with lt

```
* {
    --ctBackground: var(--dtBackground);
    --ctTopBgPattern: var(--dtTopBgPattern);
    --ctCardBg: var(--dtCardBg);
    --ctText1: var(--dtText1);
    --ctText2: var(--dtText2);
    --ctToggle: var(--dtToggle);

    // light theme
    --ltBackground: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --ltTopBgPattern: hsl(225, 100%, 98%);
    --ltCardBg: hsl(227, 47%, 96%);
    --ltText1: hsl(228, 12%, 44%);
    --ltText2: hsl(230, 17%, 14%);
    --ltToggle: hsl(230, 22%, 74%);

    // dark theme
    --dtBackground: hsl(230, 17%, 14%);
    --dtTopBgPattern: hsl(232, 19%, 15%);
    --dtCardBg: hsl(228, 28%, 20%);
    --dtText1: hsl(228, 34%, 66%);
    --dtText2: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    --dtToggle: var(--dtTopBgPattern);
}
```

I'm doing that with input element

```
<input type="checkbox" className="modeInput" onChange={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)} />
```

which triggers useEffect because state changes

```
useEffect(() => {
        if (darkMode) {
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctBackground", "var(--dtBackground)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctTopBgPattern", "var(--dtTopBgPattern)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctCardBg", "var(--dtCardBg)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctText1", "var(--dtText1)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctText2", "var(--dtText2)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctToggle", "var(--dtToggle)");
        } else if (!darkMode) {
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctBackground", "var(--ltBackground)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctTopBgPattern", "var(--ltTopBgPattern)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctCardBg", "var(--ltCardBg)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctText1", "var(--ltText1)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctText2", "var(--ltText2)");
            document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--ctToggle", "var(--ltToggle)");
        }
    }, [darkMode]);
```

There's no problem with useEffect because if I try to console.log inside the place where variables should change it works just fine.

Comment: Pleasse put your code into your question - in particular we cannot tell from your description which variables you are changing and how and on what elements with the JS.

Comment: @AHaworth Done, thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved when I define css variable in :root instead of *, so correct css looks like that:

```
:root {
    --ctBackground: var(--dtBackground);
    --ctTopBgPattern: var(--dtTopBgPattern);
    --ctCardBg: var(--dtCardBg);
    --ctText1: var(--dtText1);
    --ctText2: var(--dtText2);
    --ctToggle: var(--dtToggle);
}
```

React/javascript stays exactly the same